# rac_textSignal in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, signals, reactive-cocoa

I am attempting to migrate a Swift 2.2 app that I did not write to Swift 3. All was going well until I ran into some RAC calls. I am not familiar with ReactiveCocoa, which makes this even more challenging.

```
/**
 * Method name: Enable Login Button
 * Description: Enable or disable login button based on
 * username and password entry
 * Parameters: None
 */
func enableLoginButton() -> Void {
    self.btnLogin.isEnabled = false

    let serviceUrlSignal = self.txtServiceUrl.rac_textSignal()
        .toSignalAssumingHot()
        .assumeNoErrors()
        .map { text in text as! String }

    let usernameSignal = self.txtFieldUsername.rac_textSignal()
        .toSignalAssumingHot()
        .assumeNoErrors()
        .map { text in text as! String }

    let userNameCharSignal = usernameSignal.map { $0.characters.count }

    let passwordSignal = self.txtFieldPassword.rac_textSignal()
        .toSignalAssumingHot()
        .assumeNoErrors()
        .map { text in text as! String }

    let passwordCharSignal = passwordSignal.map { $0.characters.count }

    userNameCharSignal.combineLatestWith(passwordCharSignal)
        .map
        {
            charArray in charArray.0 > 0 && charArray.1 > 0
        }
        .observe { event in
            if let buttonEnabled = event.value {
                self.btnLogin.enabled = buttonEnabled
            }
    }

    viewModel.username <~ usernameSignal
    viewModel.password <~ passwordSignal
    viewModel.serviceUrl <~ serviceUrlSignal

    btnLogin.rac_signalForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)
        .subscribeNext{
            button in
            print("Authenticate Click!")
    }
}
```

From what I understand, rac_textSignal does not exist in ReactiveSwift. Do I need to install ReactiveObjC or is there a Swift approach that I could use to replace this functionality? Thanks.

Comment: I think this will help you https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/3197

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add ReactiveCocoa in addition to ReactiveSwift.

Since the repo split, the core of what was ReactiveCocoa is now implemented in ReactiveSwift, but ReactiveCocoa adds Cocoa specific things like UIKit bindings which you'll need.

UIKit bindings are accessible via the `reactive` property, e.g. `textfield.reactive.continuousTextValues`.

Since these bindings are already correctly typed (as opposed to `rac_textSignal`), you can replace the whole chunk of

```
let usernameSignal = self.txtFieldUsername.rac_textSignal()
    .toSignalAssumingHot()
    .assumeNoErrors()
    .map { text in text as! String }

...

viewModel.username <~ usernameSignal
```

with

```
viewModel.username <~ self.txtFieldUsername.reactive.continuousTextValues
```